# jquery validate cancel or remove class

Tags: jquery, validation

**How do I cancel the jquery validate. How to close it?**

I validate the input by using jquery validate. But I want to close it when the user clicks on the "Off" button.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form[name='formData']").validate({
                rules: {
                    CompanyID: {
                        required: true
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    function validateOn() {
       $("form[name='formData']").valid();
    }
    function validateOff() {
       //How ? off red fill box and text;
    }
```

This html.

```
//inform form name='formData'
    <input type="text" id="txtCompanyID" name="CompanyID" />
    <input type="button" value="On" onclick="validateOn();" />
    <input type="button" value="Off"  onclick="validateOff();" />
```

Comment: your validation code is not working.Check

Comment: it use in form.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Company", "MasterData", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", name = "formData" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <input type="text" id="txtCompanyID" name="CompanyID" />
    <input type="button" value="On" onclick="validateOn();" />
    <input type="button" value="Off"  onclick="validateOff();" />
}

estimated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.destroy()` method. But also if you want the code to be able to stop and then start again, you need to initiate it in the `validateOn()` function like so:

```
var validator;
$(document).ready(function() {
  validateOn();
});

function validateOn() {
  validator = $("form[name='formData']").validate({
    rules: {
      CompanyID: {
        required: true
      }
    }
  });
}

function validateOff() {
  validator.destroy();
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot,but use 
var validator = $("form[name='formData']").validate();
validator.resetForm();

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe u can change ur code like that for example

```
 <input type="text" id="txtCompanyID"   /> 
 <input type="button" value="On" id="OnValidate"  />
 <input type="button" value="Off" id="OffValidate />


$( "#OnValidate" ).click(function() {
 $( "#OnValidate" ).rules( "add", { required: true});});


$( "#OffValidate" ).click(function() 
  {$( "#OffValidate" ).rules("remove");});
```